# Flutter iOS BottomAppBar Buttons

Tags: ios, flutter

For some reason the InkWell button box is not encompassing the entire Icon only in the iOS version, as in the android version everything is working fine. And this behavior happens only for the bottomAppBarBody. I use the same button style (Material > InkWell>Padding>Icon) in other parts of the app even in the iOS version and it works ok...

```
bottomAppBarBody: BottomAppBar(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 54.0),
                child: Material(
                  shape: const CircleBorder(),
                  color: ThemeColors.whiteBackGroundColor,
                  child: InkWell(
                    customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const InvoiceScreen()));
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.monetization_on_outlined,
                        size: 33.33,
                        color: ThemeColors.secondaryFontColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 54.0),
                child: Material(
                  shape: const CircleBorder(
                  ),
                  color: ThemeColors.whiteBackGroundColor,
                  child: InkWell(
                    customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
                      onTap: () {
                        if (isMovement) {
                          newMovement();
                        } else {
                          newSling();
                        }
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.directions_boat_filled_outlined,
                          size: 33.33,
                          color: ThemeColors.secondaryFontColor,
                        ),
                      )),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[Gif Image](https://s11.gifyu.com/images/SW21o.gif)